# Why is MediaWiki auto-linking the word “files”

Tags: mediawiki

Our MediaWiki installation is auto-linking the word "files".  So

```
Here are some files: a, b, c
```

would result in the word "files" being linked to `http://ourhost/mediawiki/files`.

Why is that happening and how do I make it stop? I can use the [nowiki tag](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting), but perhaps it does not surprise you that the word "files" appears often, and it is aggravating to use that tag all the time.

Here is some info on our MediaWiki installation from Special:Version.  Yes, it's old.

> Installed software
>
> Product   Version
>
> MediaWiki 1.16.5
>
> PHP   5.2.14-pl0-gentoo
> (apache2handler)
>
> MySQL 5.0.84
>
> Installed extensions
>
> Parser hooks GoogleDocs4MW (Version 1.1)  Adds  tag
> for Google Docs' spreadsheets display Jack Phoenix SyntaxHighlight
> (Version 1.0.8.6) Provides syntax highlighting  using GeSHi
> Highlighter   Brion Vibber, Tim Starling, Rob Church and Niklas Laxström
>
> WebServiceSequenceDiagram(Version 1.0)    Render inline sequence diagrams
> using websequencediagrams.com Eddie Olsson Other MWSearch MWSearch
> plugin    Kate Turner and Brion Vibber
>
> Extension functions
> efLucenePrefixSetup
>
> Parser extension tags gallery,
> googlespreadsheet, html, nowiki, pre, sequencediagram,
> source and syntaxhighlight
>
> Parser function hooks
> anchorencode,
> basepagename, basepagenamee, defaultsort, displaytitle, filepath,
> formatdate, formatnum, fullpagename, fullpagenamee, fullurl, fullurle,
> gender, grammar, int, language, lc, lcfirst, localurl, localurle,
> namespace, namespacee, ns, nse, numberingroup, numberofactiveusers,
> numberofadmins, numberofarticles, numberofedits, numberoffiles,
> numberofpages, numberofusers, numberofviews, padleft, padright,
> pagename, pagenamee, pagesincategory, pagesize, plural,
> protectionlevel, special, subjectpagename, subjectpagenamee,
> subjectspace, subjectspacee, subpagename, subpagenamee, tag,
> talkpagename, talkpagenamee, talkspace, talkspacee, uc, ucfirst and
> urlencode

Answer (score 2):

Well that's definitely not the normal behaviour of the MediaWiki syntax parsing. It must be  caused by one of those extensions. All I can suggest is try disabling them one-by-one (comment out the include in LocalSettings.php) to figure out which extension is causing it to do this.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have admin access to the box.

Comment: Well if you have FTP access (or some other file browsing access) you can download LocalSettings.php, change it, and re-upload. ...But if you can't change any files then you're unlikely to be able to fix anything.

Comment: Agreed.  However, if I could find out what it is without changing anything, I could pass that info on to the admins, and they could fix it.